# Java stack: Don't allow duplicates fragment entries into stack

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, stack

I am using a sliding menu in my application. I am storing the fragments in a stack when ever user presses the slide menu item . If i press on fragmentA it is going to stack as first element and again if i open the slide menu and pressing again on the fragmentA it is also going as second element, i want to avoid that .this is giving problem when i am using android hardware back button as two same fragments are there in stack.How to avoid it.

```
public void switchContent(Fragment fragment) {
    mContent = fragment;

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.content_frame, mContent);
    FragmentChangeActivity.fragmentStack.lastElement().onPause();
    FragmentChangeActivity.fragmentStack.push(mContent);
    ft.commit();

    getSlidingMenu().showContent();
}
```

Comment: what if you press on Fragment A then Fragment B and then again Fragment A

Comment: @KhizarHayat   Then it can be in stack as [A B A] but it should not allow [A A B A B B].  AA and BB should not go in stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void switchContent(Fragment fragment) {
if(mContent !=null && (fragment.getClass().toString().equals(mContent.getClass().toString()))){
return;
}
    mContent = fragment;

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.content_frame, mContent);
    FragmentChangeActivity.fragmentStack.lastElement().onPause();
    FragmentChangeActivity.fragmentStack.push(mContent);
    ft.commit();

    getSlidingMenu().showContent();
}
```

Comment: @ Thank you it worked. And for sliding to happen again i placed getSlidingMenu().showContent(); in the if statement.

Comment: .Hey is there any possible we can reuse the fragment if it is already in the stack? Like [A,B,C ,now clicking A should reuse first A element]

Comment: I never did it  . but as per my logic i think it is possible.
when you want  to load fragment a get FragmentList from backStack and match as we did in above code if matched then we can use that fragment.